# Syncing Core Data with iCloud

Tags: ios, core-data

How do I sync the contents of my sql file (created with core data) to iCloud so that multiple devices can access the content?

Are there any good tutorials? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's WWDC2012 video session 227 - Using iCloud with Core Data.